Ubuntu ethernet broken after and during suspend
I have an old iMac that has Ubuntu server 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-35-generic x86_64) installed.
It was previously hooked up to a router that was connected to the internet via Ethernet.
Now, it is connected to another identical iMac running macOS through a direct Ethernet cable.
In System Preferences, the ip is set to 192.168.0.33 and the netmask is 255.255.255.0
If I run sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0, the ethernet works and has the ip address 192.168.0.48 as written in /etc/network/interfaces.
ifconfig shows this:
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.48  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 3c:07:54:59:5c:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 726  bytes 91026 (91.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 549  bytes 98547 (98.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

However, if I suspend the system, wake-on-LAN does not work even though it worked perfectly before, and ifconfig shows this:
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 3c:07:54:59:5c:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 633  bytes 70825 (70.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 477  bytes 86894 (86.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

What should I do to fix this issue?

Is there a typo in ifconfig. or is the 3rd octet supposed to be 0?

What do you mean it worked before? When was before and what have you done since? Updates installed anything etc. Please edit the question and add more details.

@eyoung100 What do you mean?

Has your LAN IP always been 192.168.0.48?

@eyoung100 No. Before my Ethernet LAN IP was just like the auto one. I did not set it manually. Ubuntu must have configured it automatically.

I fixed it with this guide: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/configuring-networks

Create a new netplan with sudo nano /etc/netplan/99_config.yaml
Add these values (change the addresses and adapter name to your
config):

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.6/24


Run sudo chmod =600 /etc/netplan/99_config.yaml
Run sudo netplan apply


It is VERY important to use a different subnet for differnet interfaces.
